# SAP UIveri5 Minimum example

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to understand how UIveri5 works and how to apply it to my own projects, but due to the minimal documentation I am unable to create a minimal working example.

I tried to apply the code from https://github.com/SAP/ui5-uiveri5/blob/master/README.md to "my" minimal app ( https://ui5.sap.com/1.62.0/#/sample/sap.m.sample.Button/code/ ), but the IDE VS Code marks errors, since i.e. the commands `export` or `define` are not known and I don't see where UIveri5 loads them from. Also if I just execute `uiveri5` in my command line as is, I am getting an error ( I  guess from selenium ) that my Chrome binary is missing, but don't the drivers get downloaded automatically?

conf.js

```
exports.config = {
    profile: 'integration',

    baseUrl: 'localhost:8080/.../sap.m.sample.Button',
};
```

page.spec.js

```
describe('Page', function () {

    it('should display the page',function() {
      element(by.control({
        viewName: 'sap.m.sample.Button.Page',
        controlType: 'sap.m.Page',
        properties: {
          title: "Page"
        }}));
    });

  });
```

It would be awesome if someone already build a minimal example and can share it. It would help me very much in understanding how everything works together.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum example is right in the readme.md. The only problem I see here is with the baseUrl - this should be a valid URL to an existing app. If this is a sample app on your localhost, you need a dev server.